# Creative Commons RPG

Tags: game-recommendation, indie-rpg

I can't find a complete and generic (or fantasy) RPG system that:

- Allow me to edit the changes and distribute under a different license
- Allow me to use comercially

I want a game system using the default creative commons. I spent a lot of time searching for one. Does anyone here knows any?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Sorry man, this is a) a duplicate of another question and b) that question was closed because it doesn't fit our format.  There are thousands of RPGs and there are many published under Creative Commons.  There are links in the duplicated question that should help you along your path though!

Comment: This is not duplicate.

The previous question is about ANY creative commons work.

My question is about a comercial-friendly creative commons.

Comment: Well, it's still closable for the reason the other was - it's a list question and there's no best answer.  See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands Did you look at the wiki link in the comments on the linked Q?  I saw a bunch of ones that don't specify non-commercial. Or this list from rpggeek. http://rpggeek.com/geeklist/152738/creative-commons-rpgs

Comment: Thanks for the list, but the only option (comercial-friendly creative commons) from this list was The Vicious Crucible.

Now I have 2 options thanks to this forum.
=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### FATE Core

It's not going to printers until mid-April (2013), but FATE Core will be released under both OGL and Creative Commons (probably [CC-BY](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/)) licensing.

> **Creative Commons for Fate Core:** One of the things we've done with Fate Core is write the rules up from scratch. This got us the clearest text possible. It also meant that absolutely none of our rules text uses text written by someone outside of Evil Hat. With that kind of ground-up ownership of the text, it frees us up to do more than just the Open Gaming License (OGL) if we want -- and the most popular other-license request we've gotten over the years has been for some kind of Creative Commons licensing alternative. With this goal funded, we'll put the time in to make that a reality -- we will choose a commercial-friendly, non-viral license that fits our vision for others using Fate Core (likely CC-BY), and provide documentation for how to properly follow the license if you decide to go that path with your own derived material, as well as protocols for commingling your CC-derived work with others' OGL materials if you happen to design like Frankenstein.

(From the [FATE Core Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/evilhat/fate-core), which far surpassed the Creative Commons goal well before it closed.)

FATE Core is designed as a robust but generic system placing emphasis on narrative control, with scalable crunch levels to accomodate the designer's or gamer's playstyle preferences. There are a number of FATE games in fantasy settings if you want to see how it can work in action (the *Dresden Files RPG* is their flagship production), and the Core release will be accompanied by generic modules and guidelines for designing one's own addons (like magic).

Also worth mentioning that FATE Core will be free to download as a pdf as soon as the physical copies are also available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

It sounds good to me. When released, I'll try to adapt it and use in my computer RPG game in development.

Comment: @vinipsmaker Ah, if it's for a computer game then FATE may not be quite as good a fit. When you hit 20 rep you can join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), where the topics of discussion aren't subject to the strict guidelines of the main site.